# Searching my friends' public facebook posts

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

so I am attempting to develop a function using Facebook's Developer Tools that will allow me to search all of my friends' public posts for a particular phrase, like "I love steak." This used to be possible using the Graph API, but as of April 30th, they no longer allow searching friends' posts. Does anyone know of another way to perform this task? I also have been researching using the Python Facebook-SDK, but I haven't found a solution in there either. Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you try any code?

Comment: Yes I did, however it worked with the Graph API V1, and since they completely changed it (causing it to not work anymore) I didn't think it was relevant.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Public Post Search is not available anymore and all friend permissions are gone too, so there is no way to do that in v2.0+.

Comment: I was hoping maybe there was another way to do the same thing. That's a bummer!